# Container is running but nothing on browser

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to containerize an Azure Function Project by using docker. My requirement is to delete logs from the docker container logs based on specific timestamp. I have build my docker file successfully, container is also running but nothing is showing on browser.

I tried this docker file to run my application in docker container with that log deletion requirement.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FunctionApp01/*.csproj", "FunctionApp01/"]
RUN dotnet restore "FunctionApp01/FunctionApp01.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FunctionApp01"
RUN dotnet build "FunctionApp01.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FunctionApp01.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y logrotate 
RUN apt-get install -y cron
 
RUN echo '/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log {' > /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
RUN echo '    missingok' >> /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
RUN echo '    notifempty' >> /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
RUN echo '    delaycompress' >> /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
RUN echo '    maxage 4m' >> /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs 
RUN echo '    rotate 7' >> /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
RUN echo '    compress' >> /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
RUN echo '    dateext' >> /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
RUN echo '    dateformat -%Y%m%d-%s' >> /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
RUN echo '    su root root' >> /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
RUN echo '    postrotate' >> /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
RUN echo '        service rsyslog rotate > /dev/null 2>&1 || true' >> /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
RUN echo '    endscript' >> /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
RUN echo '}' >> /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
 
RUN echo "* * * * * root /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf" > /etc/logrotate.d/delete_logs
 
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

Comment: This container only seems to be running background tasks; what do you expect to appear in a browser?  Also note that each container has its own isolated filesystem, and if this logrotate setup works it would only delete from the container's `/var/lib/docker/...` directory; do you need to run this administration task outside a container, directly on the host?

Answer (score 0):

This may be working correctly, but if you haven't exposed any external service to access it from a browser, you can try the following if it is a running web application:
EXPOSE 80